# Changing the color of the hidden character in Atom Text Editor

Tags: atom-editor

For some reason adding style to my style.less file doesn't seem to affect my editor. I'm trying to change the color of a hidden character. If I use this code in my style.less file:

```
atom-text-editor .invisible-character, :host .invisible-character {
  color: purple;
}
```

I don't get the color. If I check in the developer tool, this style is showing instead

```
atom-text-editor .invisible-character, :host .invisible-character {
  color: rgba(171, 178, 191, 0.15);
}
```

I don't see my styles in the dev tool. I just don't see how to get my styles to apply. I can't find documentation showing it either. Does anyone know how to do this? I am running Atom 1.2.7

Answer (score 3):

You have to modify it in the context of the shadow DOM.

```css
atom-text-editor::shadow .invisible-character {
    color: purple;
}
```

For now, at least. In Atom 1.13, they are [removing the shadow DOM](http://flight-manual.atom.io/shadow-dom/sections/removing-shadow-dom-styles/), at which point you should be able to do it using a regular selector.

```css
/* Atom 1.13 or later */
atom-text-editor .invisible-character {
    color: purple;
}
```